# Adding and Subtracting Normal Distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I think I know how to do this, but I'm not sure. I'm just hoping to check myself here before I do a bunch of work incorrectly.

Suppose you have three independent normal distributions:

Distribution $A$: Mean = $30.48$, SD = $8.15$
Distribution $B$: Mean = $16.58$, SD = $7.99$
Distribution $C$: Mean = $10.51$, SD = $4.43$

What is the probability that $B$ and $C$ will combine for a greater result than $A$?

I believe the first step is to combine distributions $B$ and $C$ into one distribution through addition. So...

Distribution $D$: Mean = $27.09$, SD = $9.135918$

Next I think I have to combine $D$ and $A$ through subtraction to get the final distribution.

Distribution $E$: Mean = $-3.39$, SD = $12.24286$

Given these values, the $z$-score using the standard normal distribution is $-.28$, so the probability of distributions $B$ and $C$ combining for a value greater than distribution $A$ is $.3897$ I think.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is correct, at least up until the distribution of E. Then you want to find the probability that a random variable with distribution E is greater than $0$.

Comment: If $X$ has distribution E, then you want
$$\mathbb{P}(X>0) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z >\frac{0 - \mu_E}{\sigma_E}\right),$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So ME = -3.39 and SDE = 12.24286. So my z score is actually a positive number in that case, which is .28. I think where I might be messing up is making the mean of distribution E negative. Is my final probablity .3897 correct?

Comment: You have found $\mu_E,\sigma_E$ correctly (the mean of distribution E *is* negative), I checked your numbers on that.  Now, define $\bar{Z} = \frac{0-\mu_E}{\sigma_E}$. As I said in the above comment, you want to compute
$$\mathbb{P}(Z > \bar{Z}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(Z \leq \bar{Z}) = 1 - \Phi(\bar{Z}),$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.  You will need to look up $\Phi(\bar{Z})$ in a table or use your calculator.

Answer (score 10):

More generally, if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent normal random variables with means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma^2_i$, and $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are
constants, 
$Y = c_1 X_1 + \ldots + c_n X_n$ is normal with mean $\mu_Y = c_1 \mu_1 + \ldots + c_n \mu_n$ and
variance $c_1^2 \sigma_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2 \sigma_n^2$.  Here you're doing the case $n=3$ with $c_1 = -1, c_2 = 1, c_3 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You did this right.  The short way to look at it is that $B+C-A$ is normally distributed with mean being $\mu = \mu_B+\mu_C-\mu_A$ and $\sigma^2 = \sigma^2_B + \sigma^2_C + \sigma^2_A$. The key point you need to know is that a variate made of the sum of two independent normal variates is itself normally distributed, *even if the means of those two variates are not the same*.

If you were given the analagous problem with, say, Poisson deviates instead, the answer would be different, and the technique for getting the answer would be more involved.

Comment: Why do you add all the variances (varB + varC + varA) for the case where two distributions are added but one subtracted (B + C -A)? Thank you!